# Entity Framework Code First Class with parent and children of same type as it's own class

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

I have a class of Content which should be able to have a parentId for inheritance but also I want it to have a list of child content which is nothing to do with this inheritance tree.

I basically wanted a link table as ChildContentRelationship with Id's for parentContent and childContent in it and the Content class would have a list of ChildContentRelationship.

This has caused a lot of errors.

Here's waht I sort of want to do

```
public class Content
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? ParentContentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Content ParentContent { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ContentTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ContentType ContentType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ChildContentRelationship> ChildContent { get; set; } 
}
```

How would I set this up in EF?

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework are you using and what kind of approach (db-first, model-first, code-first)? And why do you want a link table? Don't you have a one-to-many relationship, *one* parent and *many* children?

Comment: EF 4.1 +, Code first. It's because of this ParentContentId. See I want the Content to be able to have a parent to inherit any properties from the parents content type schema. But I also want a piece of content to have a reference to other content that isn't in this tree hierarchy. This is so I can render child content, kind of like controls. I could name it as controls and have a control have a ContentId I suppose?

Comment: "Code First" was already in the title, stupid by me, I didn't notice that, sorry.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your model correctly. Let's discuss the options.

For a moment I omit this additional entity `ChildContentRelationship` and I assume the `ChildContent` collection is of type `ICollection<Content>`.

- Option 1:

  I assume that `ParentContent` is the **inverse property** of `ChildContent`. It would mean that if you have a `Content` with `Id` = x and this Content has a `ChildContent` with `Id` = y then the ChildContents `ParentContentId` must always be x. This would only be a single association and `ParentContent` and `ChildContent` are the endpoints of this same association.

  The mapping for this relationship can be created either with data annotations ...

  ```cs
  [InverseProperty("ParentContent")]
  public virtual ICollection<Content> ChildContent { get; set; }
  ```

  ... or with Fluent API:

  ```cs
  modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
      .HasOptional(c => c.ParentContent)
      .WithMany(c => c.ChildContent)
      .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentContentId);
  ```

  I think this is not what you want (*"...has nothing to do with..."*). Consider renaming your navigation properties though. If someone reads `Parent...` and `Child...` he will very likely assume they build a pair of navigation properties for the same relationship.
- Option 2:

  `ParentContent` is not the inverse property of `ChildContent` which would mean that you actually have two independent relationships and the second endpoint of both relationships is not exposed in your model class.

  The mapping for `ParentContent` would look like this:

  ```cs
  modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
      .HasOptional(c => c.ParentContent)
      .WithMany()
      .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentContentId);
  ```

  `WithMany()` without parameters indicates that the second endpoint is not a property in your model class, especially it is *not* `ChildContent`.

  Now, the question remains: What kind of relationship does `ChildContent` belong to? Is it a one-to-many or is it a many-to-many relationship?

  - Option 2a

    If a `Content` refers to other `ChildContent`s and there can't be a second `Content` which would refer to the same `ChildContent`s (the children of a `Content` are *unique*, so to speak) then you have a one-to-many relationship. (This is similar to a relationship between an order and order items: An order item can only belong to one specific order.)

    The mapping for `ChildContent` would look like this:

    ```cs
    modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
        .HasMany(c => c.ChildContent)
        .WithOptional(); // or WithRequired()
    ```

    You will have an additional foreign key column in the `Content` table in your database which belongs to this association but doesn't have a corresponding FK property in the entity class.
  - Option 2b

    If many `Content`s can refer to the same `ChildContent`s then you have a many-to-many relationship. (This is similar to a relationship between a user and roles: There can be many users within the same role and a user can have many roles.)

    The mapping for `ChildContent` would look like this:

    ```cs
    modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
        .HasMany(c => c.ChildContent)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(x =>
        {
            x.MapLeftKey("ParentId");
            x.MapRightKey("ChildId");
            x.ToTable("ChildContentRelationships");
        });
    ```

    This mapping will create a join table `ChildContentRelationships` in the database but you don't need a corresponding entity for this table.
  - Option 2c

    Only in the case that the many-to-many relationship has more properties in addition to the two keys (`ParentId` and `ChildId`) (for example something like `CreationDate` or `RelationshipType` or...) you would have to introduce a new entity `ChildContentRelationship` into your model:

    ```cs
    public class ChildContentRelationship
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int ChildId { get; set; }

        public Content Parent { get; set; }
        public Content Child { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public string RelationshipType { get; set; }
    }
    ```

    Now your `Content` class would have a collection of `ChildContentRelationship`s:

    ```cs
    public virtual ICollection<ChildContentRelationship> ChildContent
        { get; set; }
    ```

    And you have *two* one-to-many relationships:

    ```cs
    modelBuilder.Entity<ChildContentRelationship>()
        .HasRequired(ccr => ccr.Parent)
        .WithMany(c => c.ChildContent)
        .HasForeignKey(ccr => ccr.ParentId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ChildContentRelationship>()
        .HasRequired(ccr => ccr.Child)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(ccr => ccr.ChildId);
    ```

I believe that you want either option 2a or 2b, but I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I suppose I'm looking for option 2b, maybe the naming needs cleared up. I think it's more realistically a control and so maybe needs a different class / design. I will try tomorrow.

Comment: This is an answer! :)